# How can I use a variable between two methods in a class?

Tags: python, oop

I'm making a randomized sorting in python and I cant seem to use the variable `self.fileName` from the `__init__` method in my scramble method. I'm not sure why.

I have tried replacing 'self' with fn entirely, but then self isn't defined. I've tried using (self,fn) but there is nothing that will fit the self parameter.

```
class randomsort:
    def __init__(self,fn):
        self.fileName = fn
        print(self.fileName)

    def scramble(self):
        tempList =[]
        for i in self.fileName:
            ran = random.randrange(0,len(self.fileName))
            tempList.append(self.fileName[ran])
        print("-->",tempList)
        self.fileName = tempList

exlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
randomsort.scramble(exlist)
```

The expected output is an unsorted version of the list,but the output is:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fileName'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not instantiating the class ( i.e. you are not sending anything to the `__init__` method, only `scramble` is receiving `exlist`), and thus `self.fileName` is never defined. Instead you should do:

```
c = randomsort(exlist) # Create an instance of the object
c.scramble() # Call method scramble of instance c
```